# react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367 Error fetching data: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mern

I am encountering an error when trying to fetch data from my React application to an Express backend. The error message I'm receiving is: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON".

When I check the network tab, I see that the response is an HTML document instead of the expected JSON response. However, when I directly access the endpoint localhost:5001/test, I receive the correct JSON response.

Here's the relevant code from my Express server:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.get("/test", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = {
      isActive: true,
      count: 10,
      message: "Hello, world!",
    };

    console.log(data); // Log the data being sent

    res.json({ username: "Flavio", ...data });
  } catch (err) {
    res.send({ error: "not found" });
  }
});
//React code 
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function GetData() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/test")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  if (data === null) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Data Received:</h2>
      <p>isActive: {data.isActive.toString()}</p>
      <p>Count: {data.count}</p>
      <p>Message: {data.message}</p>
      <p>Username: {data.username}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Nothing is showing i dont know why

Comment: your code seems to be producing an error in the react scripts, specifically the part that handles JSON. 

Can I see the log of the `data` in your code?

Comment: @Hermanboxcar
if u mean in express
{ isActive: true, count: 10, message: 'Hello, world!' }
{ isActive: true, count: 10, message: 'Hello, world!' }

in the react code if i try to log data it will show
react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367 Error fetching data: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Comment: If this is your dev environment you'll probably have to proxy your requests. How you do that depends on how you're developing/building your dev code. For example, in Vite, [you can add some simple rules to the build config](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy) that will deal with that for you.

Comment: @Andy  no need to proxy in express cors library do that. the fetch is done successful i can see the "fetch" in network tab but as a html

Comment: Are you running this in a REPO?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible explanation, (I could be wrong since I don't have much info)

in `/test`, you maybe display info using the **`res.send()`** function or something similar in react (I don't do much react so I don't know). This will generate a webpage, with all the regular HTML protocols, therefore the <!DOCUTYPE... declaring the start of the HTML document.

Instead, use `res.status(200).end(yourJSONstringified)` in order to generate an status page that is not HTML, so the only content will be your JSON. I would provide a similar example in React, but I rarely do React so I am not too familiar with it.

Please note, do not put a random number as the status numbers are predefined (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) in this case use like 200 or 202, not say 400, 404, or 504

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify the host and the port

```
//React code 
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function GetData() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5001/test")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  if (data === null) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Data Received:</h2>
      <p>isActive: {data.isActive.toString()}</p>
      <p>Count: {data.count}</p>
      <p>Message: {data.message}</p>
      <p>Username: {data.username}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is not the problem since the /test page already returned something, thus the <!DOCUTYPE... error. Also, you don't **have** to specify it, when you fetch /test, and say this is being hosted on example.com, it automatically directs it to example.com/test.  Basically the /test means currentdomain/test